# s-expression parsing error with pyparsing

Tags: python, pyparsing

I'm trying to parse s-expressions with Python (v3.4.0) and pyparsing (v2.0.1). I've pondered quite a bit about the following code, but keep getting a ParseException. The code does parse e.g. "a(", but fails to parse "(a (b))".

```
import pyparsing as pp

# S-expression grammar
w = pp.Word(pp.alphanums)
lp = pp.Suppress("(")
rp = pp.Suppress(")")
sexp = pp.Forward()
sexp_list = pp.Forward()
sexp_list << (sexp | (sexp + sexp_list))
sexp << (w | (lp + sexp_list + rp))

s = "(a (b))"

try:
  pr = sexp.parseString(s)
  print(pr)
except pp.ParseException as e:
  print(e)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this diff work for you?

```
9,10c9,10
< sexp_list << (sexp | (sexp + sexp_list))
< sexp << (w | (lp + sexp_list + rp))
---
> sexp_list = pp.Group(lp + pp.ZeroOrMore(sexp) + rp)
> sexp << (w | sexp_list)
```

Comment: Thanks, that works. I'd like to understand though if there's a problem with the original code, or is it a pyparsing bug?

Comment: Not a bug, a known issue with pyparsing. You don't actually state what the problem is, but I'll make a guess. What you have specified is a left-recursive grammar, so pyparsing just recurses infinitely until it runs out of stack space. The pyparsing idiom for doing lists is what Kenji has shown here, to use OneOrMore or ZeroOrMore (or the more recent overload of multiplication).

Comment: @AnthonyKong - pyparsing overloads '<<' operator to "inject" a parsing expression into a previously defined Forward placeholder. This is necessary since Python does not allow overloading '=' assignment as an operator.